# jQuery.click not working after adding element to the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, click, jquery

I have a simple jQuery('div#star').click(function.

The function works once when the DOM is initially loaded, but at a later time, I add a div#star to the DOM, and at that point the click function is not working.

I am using jQuery 1.4.4, and as far as I know, I shouldn't need to use .live or .bind anymore. There is never more than one div#star in the DOM at any one time. I tried changing from id="star" to class="star" but that didn't help.

Any suggestions on how to get this working or why it isn't working?

I've had the .click inside the jQuery(document).ready, and in an external js file, and neither works after adding the div to the DOM.

Comment: *"I am using jQuery 1.4.4, and as far as I know, I shouldn't need to use .live or .bind anymore."* No, that's not true. When you use `click` or any of the other shortcuts for `bind`, you're dealing with whatever exists *right then*. The whole purpose of `live` and `delegate` is that you're explicitly saying "figure this out later when the event actually happens."

Comment: Thanks TJ, for some reason I thought .live had been deprecated

Answer (score 12):

This works with jQuery 2.0.3

```
$(document).on('click', '#myDiv', function() {
    myFunc();
});
```

Comment: i had the same problem. this solution worked for me. thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 9):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. The current recommendation is to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which provides all functionality covering the previous methods of attaching event handlers. Simply put, you don't have to decide any more since on() does it all.

Documentation is handily provided in the help for converting from the older jQuery event methods [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), and [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 6):

You still need to use live events.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 4):

try

`.on('event', 'element', function(){
//code })`

Comment: This seems to be the only way I got in to work in more recent jQuery versions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) here. Nothing has changed in this department since jQuery 1.4.4.

Try to think of it like this: `click` and `bind` attach an event to the element itself, so when the element disappears, all the information about the event does too. `live` attaches the event at the document level and it includes information about which element and event type to listen for. `delegate` does the same thing, except it attaches the event information to whatever parent element you like.

Answer (score 0):

user "live" method `$("div#star").live("click", function() {});`

[Doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **delegate** instead **on** :

```
$(document).delegate('click', "selector", function() {
    //your code
});
```

**I hope it will help.**